# Rokoko retargeting problem

Tags: animation, mesh, .fbx, bvh

I just started using Rokoko's retarget tool and I'm having trouble pinpointing where the issue is coming from. I made an animation and exported it as BVH and it was fine. But, as soon as I retarget it to another rig, the mesh glitches out. I do not know if it is because of my animation or just how Rokoko retargets them. Any solutions to this?

Thank you!

[image: Before Retargeting]

[image: After Retargeting]

Comment: UPDATE: I figured out that the way it is exported messes up the retarget. My only problem now is how to export it so that it doesn't mess up the bones. I have used stock BVH files from the program I used and those are the ones that do not break. Anyone know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set *Use Pose* to *Current* instead of *Rest*.